# WPF. Как сделать событие на изменение статического поля

Tags: wpf, события

Вопрос состоит в следующем, мне надо создать событие, которое реагирует на динамическое изменение (при работе с программой) статического поля (булевое, тру-фолс), которое в свою очередь изменяется из других классов (это не нужная инфа). Событие должно "мониторить" это статическое поле и реагировать сразу на его изменение. 
Не сильно разбираюсь в таких событиях, можете подсказать плиз?

Comment: А класс, в котором находится поле, можно менять?

Comment: поле находится в классе MainWindow, делать с ним можно все, что не запрещено)

Comment: Окей, ситуация проясняется. А зачем вам _статическое_ поле? Ведь у вас всё равно только один экземпляр `MainWindow`? И да, зачем вам событие, что вы собираетесь с ним делать? Binding?

Comment: Это называется говнокод) статическое поле использую для возможности с любого места установить тру/фолс. Это поле относится к Visibility страницы. 
По простому это свойство доступно лишь в коде страницы для элементов только этой страницы
(Название_элемента.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden), а вот из другой страницы/окна к нему путь закрыт. Хочу сделать событие, которое находилось бы на каждой страничке и отслеживало, надо ли ее показывать или скрывать.
Архитектура моего приложения - это страницы и окна, мне надо иметь возможность с любого места приложения открывать/скрывать нужные страницы.

Comment: Так это можно и с нестатическим свойством :) Например, как-то так: `(MainWindow)(Application.Current.MainWindow).Visibility = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку `MainWindow` скорее всего существует в единственном экземпляре, то имеет смысл не заморачиваться, и перевести статическое в нестатическое свойство.

При этом если вам нужно абстрактное событие при установке свойства, проще всего делать это так:

```
bool field;
public bool Field
{
    get { return field; }
    set
    {
        if (field != value)
        {
            field = value;
            FieldChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public event EventHandler FieldChanged;
```

С другой стороны, если речь идёт о WPF, вам наверняка захочется привязаться к этому значению. Для этого лучше сделать из свойства `DependencyProperty`. Это делается так:

```
public bool Field
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(FieldProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FieldProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Field", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow),
                                new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

(для этого у Visual Studio есть сниппет `propdp`). Имея вот такое свойство, вы можете привязываться к нему из вашего XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел другое решение...
1. Статическое поле (про которое писал).
2. В конструкторе отправляем статический экземпляр этого окна:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PROVIDER.Get_mw = this;
        }
```

3. Создаем класс, который принимает этот экземпляр и делаем что хотим с элементами этого окна:

```
class PROVIDER
    {
        public static bool AutoShowStatus = true;
        public static MainWindow Get_mw { get; set; }
        public void ChangeVisibility()
        {
            if (AutoShowStatus == false) Get_mw.Autor.Visibility =
               Visibility.Hidden;
            else Get_mw.Autor.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```